Need to Redirect to particular url path without changing path in browser address bar
I have nginx conf need to redirect to another url path without showing path in address bar
I need to redirect my root domain (for e.g example.com) to (https://user1.abc.com/template3/home) - this particular url path so i have attached the nginx configuration below. It wokring but issues is that redirection path is showing in browser address bar like (example.com/template3/home) so i need same content but don't display path in browser bar.
nginx.conf
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name *.example.com example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

    large_client_header_buffers 4 32k;
    location / {
        rewrite ^/$ /template3/home permanent;
        proxy_pass https://user1.abc.com;
        proxy_set_header Host user1.abc.com;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name *.example.com example.com; 

    large_client_header_buffers 4 32k;
    
    location / {
        rewrite ^/$ /template3/home permanent;
        proxy_pass https://user1.abc.com;

        proxy_set_header Host user1.abc.com;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }    
}

Thanks in advance, lemme know is it possible or any other way to achieve this?
